# How to list files being linted by ESLint

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

How can I get a list of the files ESLint is checking?

The only talk about it I can find is [this eslint issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2152) where a member of the repo suggested running `DEBUG=eslint:* eslint`. However, the output from that is impossibly large.

Answer (score 36):

A close look at the output shows a single line with `eslint:cli-engine Lint` before the filename. Knowing that we can narrow the debug statement based on the output (`eslint`v8).

`DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine eslint`

As the OP in the linked issue suggested, a `--list-files` option seems like a no brainer for `eslint` to add.

Comment: If you don't have eslint installed globally, try `DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine npx eslint`.